# How to apply Indentation for Robot Framework code using pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework with Pycharm IDE for DataBase Data Validation. When i Use any execute query with Raw sql query goes out of the indentation line. how to break a long query and fit within the pycharm indentation line.

ex :

```
  ${client}=  DB2.query  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT host.id) FROM a.host,a.Host host WHERE host.client_id = host.client_id AND host.host_id = host.id AND host.client_id = ${client_id} AND host.status = 'OPEN';
```

Please find the below attached screenshot too.
I want

```
host.host_id = host.id AND host.client_id = ${client_id} AND host.status = 'OPEN';
```

to be moved to next line.
I tried using "\" or "/" it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Robot Framework built-in variable `${\n}` to add a newline character wherever you want.

For example:

```
 ${client}=  DB2.query  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT host.id) FROM a.host,a.Host host WHERE host.client_id = host.client_id AND ${\n} host.host_id = host.id AND host.client_id = ${client_id} AND host.status = 'OPEN';
```